# FC when adding another EditTextPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a working XML preferences, but when i add it another EditTextPreference the preference activity keeps FCing:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Prochain vidange">
<EditTextPreference
        android:name="Prochain vidange"
        android:summary="Prochain vidange:"
        android:defaultValue=""
        android:numeric="integer|decimal"
        android:title="Prochain vidange:"
        android:key="proch" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Whole XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Kilométrage/prix">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:name="KM après vidange"
        android:summary="Kilométrage après vidange:"
        android:defaultValue=""
        android:numeric="integer|decimal"
        android:title="Kilométrage après vidange:"
        android:key="km" />

        <EditTextPreference
        android:name="Prix du vidange"
        android:summary="Prix du vidange:"
        android:defaultValue=""
        android:numeric="integer|decimal"
        android:title="Prix du vidange:"
        android:key="prix_vidange" />
 </PreferenceCategory>




 <PreferenceCategory android:title="Huile Moteur">
    <ListPreference
  android:title="Huile Moteur"
  android:summary="L'huile moteur mis est de..."
  android:key="listPref_huile_moteur"
  android:entries="@array/huile_moteur"
  android:entryValues="@array/huile_return"
  android:negativeButtonText="Annuler" />
  </PreferenceCategory>  



<PreferenceCategory android:title="Filtre changés">
<CheckBoxPreference
android:key="huile"
android:title="Filtre à air"
android:defaultValue="false"
android:summary="Avez vous changez le filtre à huile?" />
<CheckBoxPreference
android:key="air"
android:title="Filtre à huile"
android:defaultValue="false"
android:summary="Avez vous changez le filtre à air?" />
<CheckBoxPreference
android:key="carburant"
android:title="Filtre carburant"
android:defaultValue="false"
android:summary="Avez vous changez le filtre à essence/diesel ?" />
  </PreferenceCategory> 



<PreferenceCategory android:title="Notifications">
<CheckBoxPreference
android:key="notif"
android:title="Notifications"
android:defaultValue="false"
android:summary="Voulez vous recevoir des rappels de vidange?" />   
 <ListPreference
  android:title="Fréquence notifications"
  android:summary="Recevoir des notifications..."
  android:key="listPref_notif"
  android:entries="@array/notif"
  android:entryValues="@array/notif_return"
  android:negativeButtonText="Annuler" />
</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory android:title="Prochain vidange">
<EditTextPreference
        android:name="Prochain vidange"
        android:summary="Prochain vidange:"
        android:defaultValue=""
        android:numeric="integer|decimal"
        android:title="Prochain vidange:"
        android:key="proch" />
</PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

logcat :

```
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{carburant.android.com/carburant.android.com.Vidange}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(ContextImpl.java:2810)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.preference.Preference.getPersistedString(Preference.java:1256)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.preference.EditTextPreference.onSetInitialValue(EditTextPreference.java:154)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.preference.Preference.dispatchSetInitialValue(Preference.java:1172)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.preference.Preference.onAttachedToHierarchy(Preference.java:984)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addPreference(PreferenceGroup.java:156)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:97)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.preference.PreferenceGroup.addItemFromInflater(PreferenceGroup.java:38)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:488)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:493)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:251)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:262)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at carburant.android.com.Vidange.onCreate(Vidange.java:45)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     ... 11 more
08-16 14:23:15.688: WARN/ActivityManager(61):   Force finishing activity carburant.android.com/.Acceuil
```

What could be the problem with this strange FC ?
Thank you.

Example array:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="notif">
 <item>Chaque jour</item>
 <item>Chaque semaine</item>
 <item>Chaque mois</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="notif_return">
 <item>0</item>
 <item>1</item>
 <item>2</item>
 </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer

Comment: @Blundell:I'm not understanding you, sorry.

Comment: Read my answer :-) and check your strings.xml or arrays.xml

Comment: check `08-16 14:23:15.639: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(880):     at carburant.android.com.Vidange.onCreate(Vidange.java:45)
`, right? I suck at reading logs, but your error should be there, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Rob: addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.vidange);

Comment: Oh, so that isn't all that helpful. Nevermind.

Comment: @Rob: exactly. Never had such strange problem.

Comment: @Rob problem solved, i just re-managed all my preferences, surely a cause of desorder :D.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting one of your arrays to an integer-array? (android:entries="@array/blah")

There is a known bug you have to use **string-array** for xml preferences sorry!

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2096

*EDIT*

Also possible is your setting your EditTextPreference to of type Integer but your setting the default value of "" which could be a string.

Comment: All my arrays are on string the values and the return values.

Comment: I posted an example of the structure of arrays that i'm using. The problem is i have the FC just when adding the first EditTextPreference("proch")

Comment: problem solved, disorder of my preferences. BUT i'm always unable to set a value for an EditTextPreference :(. I opened a topic of that if you remember.

Comment: so did you try setting the default value to "0"?

Comment: Find it ;). I choose another method: `EditTextPreference myEditTextPreference = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("proch");
           myEditTextPreference.setText(z);`